# Selectpdf - cannot remove top margin on page

Tags: c#, html, css, email, selectpdf

I am using `SelectPdf`, and when configuring my converter to convert the string to a pdf, my pdf keeps ending up generating some margin on the top of the page.

**My converter:**

```
private Stream ConvertToPdf(string data)
{
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

    converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
    converter.Options.AutoFitWidth = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.NoAdjustment;
    converter.Options.DisplayFooter = true;
    converter.Options.DisplayHeader = true;
    converter.Options.MarginTop = 0;
    converter.Options.MarginBottom = 0;
    converter.Options.DisplayHeader = false;
    converter.Options.DisplayFooter = false;
    converter.Options.CssMediaType = HtmlToPdfCssMediaType.Screen;
    converter.Options.EmbedFonts = true;
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(data);

    // create memory stream to save PDF
    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();

    // save pdf document into a MemoryStream
    doc.Save(pdfStream);
    pdfStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return pdfStream;
}
```

In my template, I have no apparent margin in the top of the page, so I am, so far, unable to figure out where it is coming from.

**My template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .red-color {
            color: red;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        p.red-color {
            margin-top: 0;
            font-weight:800;
        }

        p.red-color:first-of-type {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        h1.red-color {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top:0;
        }
        h2.red-color {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width:750px;
            height:1050px;
        }

        .image-wrapper {
            width: 96%;
            height: 350px;
            margin-left: 2%;
            position: relative;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #info-banner {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: red;
            width: 96%;
            margin-left: 2%;
            height: 125px;
        }

        #info-banner #banner-left {
            float:left;
            width:40%;
        }
        #info-banner #banner-right {
            float:left;
            width:60%;
        }

        #info-banner #banner-left a {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #info-banner #banner-left a img{
            width:50px;
        }
        #info-banner #banner-right p:first-of-type {
            margin-top:20px;    
        }
        #info-banner #banner-right p {
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .amount {
            text-align:left;
            padding-left:5px;
        }
        .name {

        }
        .price {

        }
        table th {
            text-align: left;
        }

        td {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

        table {
            width: 96%;
            margin-left:2%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .top-border {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
        }

        .heavy-font {
            font-weight: 800;
        }
        .less-spacing td{
            padding:5px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="page-break-after: always">
    <h1 class="red-color">Name</h1>

    <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url('@@EventImage@@');"></div>

    <h2 class="red-color">@@Title@@</h2>
    <p class="red-color">your ticket:</p>
    <p class="red-color">Print it.</p>

    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="top-border">
                <td class="amount">@@Amount@@</td>
                <td class="name">
                    @@Title@@<br />
                    Adresse: @@Address@@ <br />
                    Dato: @@Date@@<br />
                    Tidspunkt: @@Time@@
                </td>
                <td class="price">@@Price@@ USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="top-border ">
                <td class="amount"></td>
                <td class="name">In Total</td>
                <td class="price">@@ProductTotalPrice@@ USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="less-spacing">
                <td class="amount"></td>
                <td class="name">Total ex. tax:</td>


  <td class="price">@@ProductTotalExTax@@ USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="less-spacing">
            <td class="amount"></td>
            <td class="name">shipping: </td>
            <td class="price">@@ShippingPrice@@ USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="less-spacing">
            <td class="amount"></td>
            <td class="name">Subtotal ex. tax</td>
            <td class="price">@@PriceNoTax@@ USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="less-spacing">
            <td class="amount"></td>
            <td class="name">tax</td>
            <td class="price">@@Tax@@ USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top-border">
            <td class="amount"></td>
            <td class="heavy-font name">Total:</td>
            <td class="heavy-font price">@@FinalPrice@@ USD</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="info-banner">
        <div id="banner-left">
            <a href="#"><img src="facebook-icon.png" /><br />Find us on facebook</a>
        </div>
        <div id="banner-right">
            <p>Name</p>
            <p>Address</p>
            <p>Second Address</p>
            <p>Phone: 0000000000 Email: info@test.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I generate this, I have no issues making it a pdf, but on each page it appears with a top margin, or some sort of a header.

Comment: have you tried `body { margin:0; padding:0; }` ?

Comment: @Roysh, yep, it is already added at the very top of the template.

Comment: Are you talking about the space between Name and @@Title@@ ?

Comment: Above the h1, i have what appears to be almost eighty pixels of space..

Comment: I've put your code in a fiddle and the only space I see is about the h2. 
No top margin above h1

Comment: @Roysh which is exactly my problem... when viewing my template, no spacing appears, but then i convert it to a pdf, and then spacing appears.

Comment: Well, for what I can say, the problem doesn't seem to come from the HTML itself. There's something in converting it to pdf that causes it

Answer (score 1):

Setting these values appears to have solved my issue.

```
converter.Options.WebPageHeight = 1050;
converter.Options.WebPageWidth = 750;
```

and i had duplicated values in these, which said true.

```
converter.Options.DisplayHeader = false;
converter.Options.DisplayFooter = false;
```